# Finding the first value in a row and getting the address using ArrayFormula

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, string-matching

[image]

in this example table, I want to get the first "failed" or "passed" from result 1, 2, and 3 column. I already made a formula to get the first mentioned value using:

=IF(C2=C2,CELL("address",INDEX(D2:F2,MATCH(C2,D2:F2,0))),)

which works fine (the column result is from that formula)

But when I'm trying to use ArrayFormula on the formula, it only shows the first row value only. my ArrayFormula is like this:

=ArrayFormula(IF(C2:C4=C2:C4,CELL("address",INDEX(D2:F2,MATCH(C2:C4,D2:F2,0))),))

[image]

i think its because the INDEX and MATCH doesn't update as it goes down, any idea how to fix this?

Sheets link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oFTZHGd9PKpfZ9QXWvTshorEOGFxmD1cpeeQ9bIOYh8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Make sure to add input and expected output as **text table** (NOT as IMAGE/LINK) to the question. [Click here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to create a table easily. Adding such tables greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer, as **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). Your table should be a [mre].[Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a query to get the minimum column matching the value in column C for each row in D to F:

```
=ArrayFormula(lambda(a,address(index(a,,1),index(a,,2)))
(query(split(flatten(if(C2:C="",,if(D2:F=C2:C,row(C2:C)&"|"&column(D2:F),))),"|"),"select Col1,min(Col2) where Col2 is not null group by Col1 label min(Col2) ''")))
```

[image]

Or alternatively you can use a formula similar to your original one with Byrow:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(C2:C="",,byrow(C2:F,lambda(r,CELL("address",INDEX(r,1+MATCH(index(r,,1),index(r,,2):index(r,,columns(r),0))))))))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! it works. i might need to spend time to learn the formula (i'm not an adept formula coder.). really appreciate it